# creating a android library in eclipse . i get the below error. Is there any library i need to add?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

1:  Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.app.Activity. Fix the build path then try building this project    Androidd  Unknown   Java Problem

2:Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type android.app.Activity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    MainActivity.java   /Androidd/src/com/example/Androidd  line 1  Java Problem

Comment: Eclipse has be depreciated for over [2 years](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html) Please use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Comment: as this is a old project i tried running it in the eclipse first. Anyways i tried importing in the studio too , but i find the java files to be in red round in J. does that causes any ?

Comment: Then be aware that even if you have a machine untouched from Eclipse ADT time period (including Java SDK and Android SDKs), you'll have to work out the error messages by searching. Most everyone reading would be aware of Android Studio issues and forgot about Eclipse errors. You would have to go through the errors one by one to fix (I would start with names and build paths per your error - 'Android' vs 'Androidd' with extra 'd'). It may even be easier to copy the files into a new Android Studio project, and working through each error there. Good luck.